# Just one server fails to read from stateserver

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, load-balancing, state-server

Two servers works with state server correctly. But the new third server fails to read values, stored by 1st or 2nd servers.

1. MachineKeys are the same.
2. Application Path the same.

What else could cause such behavior? Windows2003 & iis6 on each server.

Answer (score 1):

Is the site ID the same too?  That also needs to be the same.  I assume it reads, but just doesn't read the correct information?  If so, that means that it's not the firewall, DNS or network.  If it doesn't even read then I would check firewall, DNS and network.